# new image show CREATED as 2 weeks and 4 months ago inside docker?

Tags: docker

I used docker some months ago &  I clear all container & images but when I install new images it show CREATED as 2 weeks ago and 4 month  ago  I don't understand as I installed new images now but why it is showing CREATED as 2 weeks and 4 month ago ?

> REPOSITORY         TAG           IMAGE ID        CREATED        SIZE
>
> ubuntu            latest         1d622ef86b13    2 weeks ago    73.9MB
>
> hello-world       latest         bf756fb1ae65    4 months ago   13.3kB

Comment: I have the same problem. is it already solved?

Answer (score 1):

The images have been created months ago by the image maintainers. The created date does not reflect when you downloaded them on your machine or when you started an image.

Comment: Thanks!. but how I am getting the 2 weeks ago for base Image(Based on what logic?). for eg.
$ docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE

ubuntu                  latest    c29284518f49   10 days ago          72.8MB

Answer (score 0):

"CREATED", counter-intuitively perhaps, reflects **the date the highest layer in your image was built**.

So if:

1. You run an image from a container registry somewhere (eg. `docker/getting-started`) with no modifications:

   1. "CREATED" gets set to the date that the 3rd-party image was created
2. You build an image based on a `Dockerfile` you've created:

   1. then "CREATED" gets set to the build date of the highest layer. If, as outlined [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34786), your `Dockerfile` consists only of the `FROM` command and some `CMD` settings, then the build date of the image specified in `FROM` applies. Other `Dockerfile` statements like `COPY` will create a new layer and therefore update the "CREATED" field.